# Loading and accessing multiple ctype instances

Tags: python, ctypes

I have some existing C code that I am working with in Python.  I am able to load the library using the following commands:

```
library_path = '/full/path/to/my/library.dylib'
lib1 = cdll.LoadLibrary(library_path)
```

The problem is that I need to have multiple instances of this library, for example:

```
lib2 = cdll.LoadLibrary(library_path)
```

This creates a second instance, but both seem to have the same memory location (handles are the same).  I've tried copying and renaming *library.dylib* to *library1.dylib* and *library2.dylib*, but this doesn't change how they load.  The problem is that when I call function in **lib1**, global and state variables in **lib2** are modified.  For example:

```
lib1.open('/path/to/myfile')  # open a file for processing
lib1.run()   # This will do something with the file

lib2.open('/path/to/anotherfile')  # open a file for processing
lib2.run()   # This will do something with the file

lib1.close() # Closes library 1

lib2.run()   # This fails because lib1.close() also closes lib2
```

Is there any way to load these library instances in way that they remain 'contained'?  The C code that I am trying to load is very large legacy software...do I need to do some rewriting?

Here is a link that I found addressing a similar problem, but doesn't help me that much: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/826703

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As you noticed, some OS refuses to load several instances of the same DDL in the same process. If everything else failed, you might use the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module to fork your program, and load each DLL in a different process.

Comment: Check (newer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54243176/independent-cdll-library-instances-with-ctypes/54257116#54257116. The behavior is for *Lnx* (same behavior on *Win*), so I'd expect to also be the same on *OSX*.

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, some OS refuses to load several instances of the same DDL in the same process. If everything else failed, you might use the [multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) to fork your program, and load each DLL in a different process. – Sylvain Leroux Jan 27 '15 at 22:20

Answer (score 0):

An answer given to a question on circular imports may (or may not) hold a solution to your issue.

Here is the original thread: [Circular Imports Hell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691411/circular-imports-hell)

This is the relevant part that you may find interesting, as originally posted by Sebastian Wozny:

---

Begin Excerpt:

From David Beazleys excellent talk Modules and Packages: Live and Let Die! - PyCon 2015, 1:54:00, here is a way to deal with circular imports in python:

```
 try:
     from images.serializers import SimplifiedImageSerializer
 except ImportError:
     import sys
     SimplifiedImageSerializer = sys.modules[__package__ + '.SimplifiedImageSerializer']
```

This tries to import SimplifiedImageSerializer and if ImportError is raised, because it already is imported, it will pull it from the importcache.

End Excerpt:

---

I hope this is helpful. -Science_1