# python cdll LoadLibrary and library resources relative paths

Tags: python, resources, dynamic-dll-import

I'm trying to load the shared library which internally uses some resources. File structure is the following:

```
dir_a/script.py
dir_a/lib/lib.so
dir_a/model/model.bin
```

From `script.py` I'm using the following code to load tge library:

```
from ctypes import *
from os import path

script_dir = path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__))
lib_path = path.join(script_dir, "lib/lib.so")
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path )
```

This allows me to run the script not only from script directory, but from the other directories as well and library location is resolved properly:

```
cd dir_a/lib
python ../script.py
```

But I'm facing with `model.bin` file access issue. Looks like library tries to load it using `model/model.bin` string literal and it is resolved only when I'm running the script from `dir_a` directory.

Is it possible to somehow specify working directory to loaded library to be the root directory to relative paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely (I can't say for sure without looking at the code) *lib.so* expects the resource file to be present at *model/model.bin*. That's relative to current directory (*CWD*).

One way of overcoming this is setting it (before loading the *.so*), via [[Python.Docs]: os.chdir(path)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir):

```py
os.chdir(script_dir)
```

Might also want to check:

- [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546)
- [[SO]: Independent CDLL Library Instances with Ctypes (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54257116/4788546)